# Batch Reading from different file, and setting each two characters as a variable

Tags: batch-file

*I have a Batch File and a Text file, I want to get every two characters from that text file and save it as a variable in the batch file as a variable aka*

> txt.bat

```
[][][]
```

> batch.bat

```
px1=[] px2=[] px3=[]
```

and I want to do this for a amount of lines and b amount of double characters.

Comment: you want to take users input using batch file or you have multiple batch files and you want to create a new batch file that reads 2 chars ? can you describe more what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: I have a text file, and it has a "map" I want the batch file to take every two letters save it as a added variable, and repeat until the file reaches set amount of variables.

Comment: can you explain what you refer to map here ? also i dont get take two letters from where ? and add it to new file or same file ?

Comment: Okay, think of it as this, I want to save both characters as one variable so a=[] instead of a=[ and b=] and the "map" is pretty much a different text file.

Comment: okay got it and you want to do this via batch file only ? and cant use C / C# etc ?

Comment: you are saying, if file1 has content abcdef then form file1 read 2 chars say ab then save in file2 as "ab=[]" then from file1 read cd and store in file2 as "cd=[]" and so on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on your file where it says `"file.txt"`

It will list the variables and then pause.

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
type "file.txt"|repl "(..)" "$1\r\n" x >file.tmp
set c=100
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.tmp) do (
set /a c+=1
set num=!c:~-2!
set "px[!num!]=%%a"
)
set px[
del file.tmp
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set amount=8

set i=0
set "first="
rem I have a Text file
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('cmd /U /C type textFile.txt^| find /V ""') do (
   rem I want to get every two characters from that file...
   if not defined first (
      set "first=%%a"
   ) else (
      rem and save it as a variable in the batch file...
      set /A i+=1
      set "px!i!=!first!%%a"
      set "first="
      rem and repeat until the file reaches set amount of variables
      if !i! equ %amount% goto continue
   )
)
:continue
set px
```

textFile.txt:

```
[][][]
abcdef
1234567890
```

Output:

```
px1=[]
px2=[]
px3=[]
px4=ab
px5=cd
px6=ef
px7=12
px8=34
```